# How Do I Reset the Library Templates Defaults in Xcode?

Tags: macos, iphone, templates, xcode, reset

I was attempting to try to add the [cocos2d] template to Xcode but instead of my iPhone OS templates appearing under the iPhone OS heading it is showing all the Mac OS X templates. (See screenshot).

How can I reset this back to the factory defaults?

[image: Xcode Templates]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone OS templates can be found at `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Project Templates` by default, while the Mac OS X project templates can be found at `/Developer/Library/Xcode/Project Templates`

Are there any folders/files in the folder containing the iPhone OS templates and/or are they a duplicate of the Mac OS X project template folder?

One option you can try is re-install the iPhone SDK (if necessary delete the `/Developer` folder if you want to start fresh), the other would be to restore the iPhone OS Project Template folder from a backup.